# How to extract multiple strings from between special characters

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a problem with defining the correct regex.

I need to split the text into groups in such a way that I will have a group/array of digits that are inside braces and a group/array of text that is between those braces.

Example text:

> {3} Lorem ipsum "dolor" sit amet, {2} consectetur adipiscing elit. {5}Sed semper; sollicitudin diam, "posuere" {3}aliquet massa pulvinar nec.

And I want to have two arrays:

> 1. [3,2,5,3]
> 2. ["Lorem ipsum "dolor" sit amet,", "consectetur adipiscing elit.", "Sed semper; sollicitudin diam, "posuere"", "aliquet massa pulvinar nec."]

And almost I made it, but I have a problem with special characters in a text (braces character is prohibited in input text).
My present regex:

`\{(.)\}+([\d\w\s]+)`

And it returns:

> 1. ["{3} Lorem ipsum", "{2} consectetur adipiscing elit", "{5}Sed semper", "{3}aliquet massa pulvinar nec"]

I know that later I can split numbers from text using .split('}') substring and so one, on each array element (it won't be nice but it will work).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would do it:

```js
var text = `{3} Lorem ipsum "dolor" sit amet, {2} consectetur adipiscing elit. {5}Sed semper; sollicitudin diam, "posuere" {3}aliquet massa pulvinar nec.`;

// regex for all digits encased in {}
var regex = /\d+(?=\})/g;
var nums = text.match(regex);

// regex for everything not a digit encased in {}
var regex = /[^}]+(?=\{|$)/g;
var next_text = text.match(regex);

console.log(nums);
console.log(next_text);
```

Comment: perfect :) Thank you

Comment: If you use the lookahead, you can get the match only without the capturing groups :-)

Answer (score 2):

[`String.prototype.matchAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/matchAll) returns an iterator of all matches and their capturing groups which you can then use to populate your seperate arrays.

```js
const s = `{3} Lorem ipsum "dolor" sit amet, {2} consectetur adipiscing elit. {5}Sed semper; sollicitudin diam, "posuere" {3}aliquet massa pulvinar nec.`

const reg = /\{(\d+)\}(.*?)(?=\{|$)/g;
const matches = s.matchAll(reg);

const braces = [], 
  text = [];
for (const match of matches) {
  const [_, b, t] = match;
  braces.push(b);
  text.push(t);
}

console.log(braces);
console.log(text);
```

Or mapped to an array of a shape of your choice.

```js
const s = `{3} Lorem ipsum "dolor" sit amet, {2} consectetur adipiscing elit. {5}Sed semper; sollicitudin diam, "posuere" {3}aliquet massa pulvinar nec.`

const reg = /\{(\d+)\}(.*?)(?=\{|$)/g;
const matches = Array.from(s.matchAll(reg), ([_, digit, text]) => ({digit, text}));

console.log(matches);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a similar regex and iterate each match, appending each captured group to the result array, like this:

```js
let str = '{3} Lorem ipsum "dolor" sit amet, {2} consectetur adipiscing elit. {5}Sed semper; sollicitudin diam, "posuere" {3}aliquet massa pulvinar nec.'

let regex = /\{(.)\}([^{]+)/g

let match = regex.exec(str)
let arr1 = []
let arr2 = []
while(match != null){
    arr1.push(match[1])
    arr2.push(match[2])
    match = regex.exec(str)
}
console.log(arr1)
console.log(arr2)
```

Comment: Matching a digit `\d` is a bit more specific, as the `.` can match any character except a newline.